# Execute Two batch file in same network

Tags: batch-file, synchronization

I need to execute task in two different PC in same network at same time. How can I trigger the individual Batch file in 2 PC by a master Batch file.

Comment: sounds like a Job for the nearly unknown command `waitfor`. See `waitfor /?`

Comment: @Stephan, it would be very nice if you posted an answer using `waitfor`, including some sample code (I never heard of the command before, thank you!)...

Comment: @aschipfl wouldn't that serve a "write-my-code-for-me request?" ;) Anyway -  see my answer.

Comment: @Stephan, I agree... I was thinking about providing a brief answer using `waitfor`, because I experimented a bit with it, but I didn't want to steal your idea... thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see multiple approaches:

1) Create a scheduled task in Windows (I assume you are using Windows)

2) Use some remote executing technology like psexec by sysinternals

3) Start the programs and have them wait for a signal sent over the network, perhaps checking for some file on a shared drive will be sufficient already

Answer (score 2):

When "at the same time" means "plus/minus some (dozend) seconds (depending how much the time differs on the different systems), a scheduled task is fine.

If you want to synchronize (plusminus some (dozend) milliseconds, use the `waitfor` command. (for more Information see `waitfor /?`).

Note, this wouldn't START anything on the other Computers, it only sends a trigger Signal. If there is no Receiver (`waitfor <same trigger string>`) on the other end, it wouldn't do anything)

Example:

Slave.bat (running on other Computer(s)):

```
@echo off
echo waiting for Signal to continue...
waitfor /t 300 StartNow
if %errorlevel%==0 (
  echo Signal received, continuing.
  goto :continue
) 
echo Timeout, no Signal received.
Exit /b
:continue
echo I'm doing stuff now.
```

Master.bat

```
@echo off
echo sending Signal to all Computers in the Network...
REM slave.bat should be running now on other Computer(s)
REM because else they don't wait for the signal
waitfor /si StartNow
echo Signal sent.
```

To try, you can also use mutliple `cmd` windows on the same Computer instead of different Computers.